# Xcode error "local repository is in an unsupported state"

Tags: xcode, git

I switched branches in Xcode 14.2 using the "keep changes" option ("apply stash"). Now Xcode behaves as if there was a unresolved merge conflict, even after I discarded all changes and did a hard git reset on the command line.

I see a yellow exclamation mark next to the branch name. When I click it I get a dialog saying "repository is in conflict" with the only option "abort the current operation". But when I click that I get a message "repository is in an unsupported state".

Does anybody know how to get out of this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I had an unfinished `git bisect` running in that repo :| `git status` is your friend here